# typeScript Break a loop of method call that return Promise<any>

Tags: typescript, promise, httpclient

I have a loop that calls a method that returns an object of type `Promise<any>` If what comes back to me from the method is correct I want to break the loop. I had `break` but the loop continue:

```
for (let item of List) {
  let currentItem = item .split(',');
  
  if (flag != '0')
  {
    break;
    
  }
  this.service.getList(currentItem [0]).then(res => {
    if (res != null) {
      for (let i of res) {
        if (i.serviceName == name) {
          flag = selectIp;
                
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }).catch(res => {

  });

}
```

The Code in the Service:

```
  getList(ip: string): Promise<any> {
  const apiUrl = environment.url + '/getData';
return this.httpClient.post<any>(apiUrl, body)
  .toPromise();
```

}

The `break` is not working. The loop continue even when the `flag != '0'` and  `i.serviceName == name'`

Comment: What does this code block do? `if (flag != '0')
  {
    break;
    
  }`   Do you want to add a return here instead of break; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code. make your function async and we are using await below.

```js
for (let item of List) {

  let currentItem = item.split(',');
      
  if (flag != '0')
  {
    break;
  }

  const res = await this.service.getList(currentItem [0]);

  if (res != null) {
    for (let i of res) {
      if (i.serviceName == name) {
        flag = selectIp;         
        break;
      }
    }
  }
    
}
```